# Broken installation of lxml in venv cannot be used with beautifulsoup4

Tags: python, xml-parsing

I have created a virtual environment to be used with tensorflow. I have followed the instructions from [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip):

```
virtualenv --system-site-packages -p python3 ./venv
```

I have installed the necessary modules including *beautiful soup 4 (bs4)* and *lxml* using

```
pip install beautifulsoup4
pip install lxml
```

which seemed successful. But when I am trying to parse an xml file I am getting an error like I haven't installed *lxml*:

```
with open(path/to/xml.file)) as f:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(f, 'xml')
```

> bs4.FeatureNotFound: Couldn't find a tree builder with the features
>   you requested: xml. Do you need to install a parser library?

If I try other parsers work as expected (or something like that):

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(f, 'html.parser')
```

seem to work fine while:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(f, 'html5lib')
```

load successfully but does not read the xml properly. Not an issue here though.

For some reason my lxml installation seems broken.

Pip reports it installed but I cannot uninstall or downgrade it to a different version. For example:

```
pip uninstall lxml
```

> Found existing installation: lxml 3.5.0
>   Not uninstalling lxml at /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages, outside environment /home/xxxxx/tensorflow_1-15_GPU
>   Can't uninstall 'lxml'. No files were found to uninstall.

Does anyone has an idea how to forcefully uninstall *lxml* or at least solve the issue?

I am using Ubuntu 16.04, python 3.6, beautifulsoup4 4.4.1 and lxml 3.5.0

Edit:
I have switched to python3.6 recently and it seems I am missing some libraries. Trying to downgrade *lxml* reports (among others) an error:

> pyconfig.h: No such file or directory

which might be the reason for my broken module. I don't have such a file for python3.6. Only python2.7 and python3.5m (what is 3.5m I am wondering though).

Comment: Did you activate your virtual environment before installing `beautifulsoup4` and `lxml`??

Comment: Yes, installation of both was inside venv

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I mentioned in the edit an error message was thrown (only) when I was trying to downgrade *lxml*:

> pyconfig.h: No such file or directory

which led me to inspect the actual libraries for python3.6. They were missing and after installing them by using:

```
sudo apt install python3.6-dev
```

the problem was fixed.